# Novel about space marine dealing with relativity?

Tags: story-identification, space, military-sf

I read half a book in a library a while ago that followed a guy from the first set of marines to actually go fight. They have gel-pod-beds to survive accelerations in space. after the first mission, which goes poorly, he gets back to earth like 20 years later and finds everyone else got really old, there's massive crowding, and society has gotten very corrupt. He rescues his fellow female marine from her family farm, and they go back into service, wanting to escape but not really being able to deal with society as it races past them.

Any ideas on what this book is called?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That would be [The Forever War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War) by Joe Haldeman.

Amusing side note:  The Female marine you mention?  'Marygay Potter'; that's also the maiden name of Halderman's wife; Mary Gay Potter.  Also, Mandela isn't QUITE an anagram of Halderman... But just about.

Comment: I assume the male marine is named Mandela?

Comment: @DCShannon - Somewhat -- it's his last name.  His full name is 'William Mandella.'