# Please help identify an old scifi comic book ~1970-1990

Tags: story-identification

I remember only last part of comic book:

- There is a scene of attack (in space) against aliens, hero is flying space shuttle.
- He return to active duty, there is a war with enigmatic aliens, after hospital **he is trained in virtual reality environment**
- **Main planet of aliens is spotted and humans send ship against it, journey in one direction takes several years**, hibernation is needed.
- Near alien planet ship is hitted by meteor or advanced alien stealth rocket.
- Humans fight with aliens and use **generators which slows down time/movements (now I know it was stasis field, inside it fight with melee weapon started, remember Einstein quote about next war after third world war)** it makes rifles and lasers useless, instead of it humans use bows and swords, the year is around 3000DC
- After battle hero backs to Earth (50 or more passed), now it seems that there is peace between aliens and humans
- Faces of aliens are not shown even one time I think, they are humanoid and in space suits

Comment: I remember only twisted parts ;) I think it was a single volume

Comment: This is the store of Joe Halderman's [*The Forever War*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War) (a novel that ever SF fan should read), but I don't know the comic.

Comment: @dmckee this is it ! I'm shocked that such short description is enought

Comment: Short? That is admirably terse, but very complete.

Comment: @dmckee there is an comic book also : 
 
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War_%28comics%29 please post it as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The story you've laid out is that of [Joe Haldeman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Haldeman)'s classic and Nebula Award winning [*The Forever War*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War), which was originally (1974) a short novel.

There is a [graphic novel version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War_%28comics%29) from 1988.

The novel is sometimes touted as a response to Heinlein's *Starship Troopers*, and certainly presents a more cynical view of the motives and behavior of the military command at the strategic and political level while retaining a strong focus on the experience of the individual soldier (Haldeman had served in Vietnam)

Comment: wiki says there is also sequel called 'A New Beginning'

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4712/novel-about-space-marine-dealing-with-relativity/4713 for question re: the original novel